# How to use Humanize inside @Html,DisplayFor()

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How can I display Date Humanizely inside `DisplayFor`?

I tried like this : `@Html.DisplayFor(model =>model.EndDate.Humanize())`

but editor shows error like:

> an expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses
>   optional arguments

Comment: You cannot use a method in an expression. What is `.Humanize()`?

Comment: Humanize - function from Humanizer package, that shows datetime in readable way , like: 20.10.2018 >> 5 days ago

Comment: Then just use `@Model.EndDate.Humanize()` - there is no point using `DisplayFor()` in your case

Comment: Stephen Muecke, Thank youu for helping,  you are right)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Html.DisplayFor` is a templated helper, which just means it returns the value of the model expression using a template. The default template is simply calling `ToString()` on the property referenced by the model expression. As such, what you pass into it must be a model expression referencing a particular property; you cannot do something like call `Humanize` on it.

However, you can define your own template. This entails creating a view in `Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates`, which conforms to one of these naming conventions:

1. It's named after the type it should be used for, e.g. `DateTime.cshtml` will be applied to any property that is of type `DateTime`.
2. It's named after one of the members of the `DataType` enum, in which case, it's utilized when that `DataType` is applied to a particular property, e.g. `Date.cshtml` will be utilized when you apply the attribute `[DataType(DataType.Date)]`.
3. It's named whatever you like, but that name is explicitly specified for the property using the `UIHint` attribute, e.g. if you apply an attribute like `[UIHint("MyAwesomeDateTime")]` and associated `MyAwesomeDateTime.cshtml` view will be used.

As such, if you were to create a view like `Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates\DateTime.cshtml` with the contents:

```
@model DateTime
@Model.Humanize()
```

Then, simply calling `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.EndDate)` will return the humanized date you're looking for. Since `EndDate` is a `DateTime`, `DisplayFor` will utilize your `DateTime.cshtml` template, which outputs the model (your `DateTime` with `Humanized` chained.

An alternative way to specify a display template is to pass it in directly. This is useful when you have a one-off situation and you don't want the template to apply to *everything* of a particular type. For example, if you just wanted `EndDate` humanized, but other dates to display as normal, that could be achieved by doing something like:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.EndDate, "HumanizedDate")
```

You would then of course need an associated `HumanizedDate.cshtml`. You can also employ `UIHint` on your property as described above here, if you'd prefer to keep this out of the view, and on your model instead.

All that said, display templates are best utilized when there's complex constructions involved. As Stephen pointed out in the comments below your question, you could easily just do: `@Model.EndDate.Humanize()`, which not only is more terse and explicit than `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.EndDate)`, but also doesn't require adding custom views or attributes to your model properties.

Comment: Chris Pratt, Thank you a lot, you explained so clearly, Respect